# CIrcular cards slider

Tags: javascript

I have created this codepen based on a resource, I need to move the slider to the left or to the right every time I drag the mouse (left or right). Something like this https://fuegocaminaconmigo.com/about/ (if you scroll down you will find the desired effect).

I have created a simple animation but it would be nice to move the slide smoothly and stop when a card reach the middle of the slider, any help is welcome. Thanks!

This is my codepen
https://codepen.io/pixelmary/pen/xxBVNeq

```
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const items = +getComputedStyle(circle).getPropertyValue("--items");
let index = 0;
let divOverlay = document.querySelector(".circleCarousel");
let dragged = false;
let oldX = 0;

//animation right
const animateCardsRight = () => {
  const step = 360 / items;
  circle.style.setProperty("--rotation", `${step * index * -1}deg`);
  index = index + 1;
};

//animation left (I think this both functions left and right can be resolved in 1 with index + 1 or index - 1)
const animateCardsLeft = () => {
  const step = 360 / items;
  circle.style.setProperty("--rotation", `${step * index * -1}deg`);
  index = index - 1;
};

//mouse move functions
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  oldX = e.pageX;
  dragged = false;
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
  dragged = true;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  if (dragged == true && e.pageX < oldX) {
    direction = "left";
    animateCardsRight();
  } else if (dragged == true && e.pageX > oldX) {
    direction = "right";`your text`
    animateCardsLeft();
  }
});
```

This is the desired effect
https://fuegocaminaconmigo.com/about/  (scroll down)`